# Getting second p tag inside a specific ID from HTML ysubg DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

How can I get content from the second `<p>` tag inside a div with ID `mydiv` using DOMDocument?

For example, my HTML might look like:

```
<div class='mydiv'>
<p><img src='xx.jpg'></p>
<p>i need here</p>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to extract the following text:

```
i need here
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Getting the contents from nth `<p>` tag:**

Use [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get all the `<p>` tags, and use [`item()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) to retrieve the node value of the second tag from the returned `DOMNodeList`:

```
$index = 2;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
echo $tags->item(($index-1))->nodeValue; // to-do: check if that index exists
```

**Getting the contents from nth`<p>` tag inside a div with given ID**

If you want to retrieve the node value of a `<p>` tag inside a specific ID, then you can use an XPath expression instead of `getElementsByTagName()`:

```
$index = 2;
$id    = 'mydiv'

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query(
    sprintf('//div[@id="%s"]/p', $id)
);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/95964)

Comment: @user3147942, That was not the question what you asked. However, to do that you need to pass `div` inside the `getElementsByTagName` as used by Amal.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Hate when that happens! I've updated the question to include the new requirement though ;)

Comment: may i use this to get the div via CLASS name?

Comment: @user3147942: Comments are not the place where you ask *NEW* questions. Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have a new question. That said, if you want to search for a specific `CLASS_NAME`, you can change the expression to: `'//div[contains(@class,"CLASS_NAME")]/p'`